# App Engine createUploadUrl only allows one file through when you post to it

Tags: php, html, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-platform

I am attempting to use PHP Google App Engine's `createUploadUrl` functionality ([see here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/googlestorage/user_upload#createuploadurl_options)) to capture multiple file uploads via a multipart file upload containing multiple files in the same field (e.g. `<input type="file" multiple>`). It seems that GAE strips out all but the first file on that field, as when I `var_dump($_FILES);` I get only the first file, even if multiple are selected. Note that I have used the same client-side form code to post to other services, and multiple files are uploaded.

So the question is: Does GAE not actually allow multiple files to be uploaded in this manner, even though the docs suggest otherwise?

**URL Generation code:**

```
<?
use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
$options = ['gs_bucket_name' => 'bucket-name-here'];
echo(CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('/upload', $options));
?>
```

**Client-side code (generated by Rails):**

```html
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="[GAE upload url dynamically generated here]" class="scene-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label class='btn btn-default btn-file'>Browse for files <input multiple name='files' style='display: none;' type='file'></label>
  </div>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <input class='scene-submit btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Upload'>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Upload URL Endpoint Code:**

```
<?
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

Comment: note: cross-posted as a GitHub issue here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-sdk/issues/11